# Slideshow does not want to automatically transition

Tags: css, slideshow, transition, fade

Hi guys so I am creating a website and on the homepage I would like to make the 3 images fade in and out of each other and I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. The images change if I press next but when I want them to transition by themselves after a certain time they don't. Here is my code in CSS, thanks for the help.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);

html, body { background: #333     url("http://codepen.io/images/classy_fabric.png"); }

.slides {
padding: 0;
width: 800px;
height: 534px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}

.slides * {
user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
top: 0;
opacity: 0;
width: 800px;
height: 534px;
display: block;
position: absolute;

transform: scale(0s);

transition: all .7s fade;

}

.slide img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

/*---.nav label {
width: 200px;
height: 100%;
display: none;
position: absolute;

  opacity: 0;
z-index: 9;
cursor: pointer;

transition: opacity 1s;


color: #FFF;
font-size: 175pt;
text-align: center;
line-height: 450px;
font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);

}
---*/

/*-- .slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; } --*/

/*-- .nav label:hover { opacity: 1; } --*/

/*-- .nav .next { right: 0; } ---*/

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
opacity: 1;

transform: scale(1);

transition: opacity 1s fade;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: none; }

.nav-dots {
width: 100%;
bottom: 9px;
height: 11px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
top: -5px;
width: 11px;
height: 11px;
margin: 0 4px;
position: relative;
border-radius: 100%;
display: inline-block;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
background: #C9C9C9;

}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
cursor: pointer;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
background: #FFFFFF;
}

input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
{
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.clearfix {
clear: both;



}
```

Comment: post the markup please

Comment: You will need a keyframes declaration to make this run automatically.Or JS. I also see one syntax error, but you are missing the absolutely essential keyframes rule here.